# Bootstrap Full Background Image Being Pushed Down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using twitter bootstrap and having an issue when trying to have the html background image display a full screen

Instead of my columns having a background image behind them they actually push the background image to the very bottom of the page instead of allowing it lay behind them.

Any ideas here?

This is whats happening [Screenshot of error](http://i44.tinypic.com/wiudyv.png)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sandbox</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"><img src="images/rock-overlook.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><img src="images/rock-overlook.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><img src="images/rock-overlook.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html { 
  background: url(../images/umbrellas.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Add `html,body{height:100%}` .. pretty sure `cover` uses a height of 100%, thus that's required.

Comment: Didn't seem to affect it.

Comment: It seemed to work with I changed it from HTML to body. Any reason why this would be?

Answer (score 3):

With Bootstrap the background of the body isn't transparent, so it is obscuring the background image you put onto the html element.  Try

```
body { background: transparent; }
```